# Nested SQL Query Returning Too Many Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables - Events and Tonight that drive a seasonal events listing system. Events holds all the seasonal event level data while Tonight holds data relevant to each individual date that an event will run.

I need to query the two tables in a nested way, first filtering out a number of rows from the Tonight table and then showing each event only once based on the previous Tonight level filtering.

I'm currently trying to do this by first selecting all relevant Event level IDs from the Tonight table and then using these to bring back the relevant Event rows. These rows need to be joined to both the Tonight Table and a further POI table to bring back all relevant data.

The problem is that my ID-based approach is bringing back multiple rows for each event due to the join on the Tonight table. I'm obviously going about this the wrong way but don't know how to remedy things. Can you please advise me?

Thanks,

PJ

```
SELECT 
    Events.ID AS ID, 
    Events.EventName AS EventName,
    Events.EventAlias AS EventAlias, 
    Events.EntryPrice AS EventPrice, 
    Events.TicketPrice AS TicketPriceText, 
    Events.MusicStyle AS MusicStyle, 
    Events.EventType AS EventType, 
    Events.CanSellEntry AS EventsCanSellEntry,
    Tonight.CanSellEntry AS TonightCanSellEntry
FROM Events
JOIN Tonight AS Tonight ON Events.Id = Tonight.Event_Id 
WHERE Events.ID in 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Events.ID AS ID 
    FROM Events 
    JOIN PlacesOfInterest AS PoI ON Events.POI_Id = PoI.Id 
    JOIN Tonight AS Tonight ON Events.Id = Tonight.Event_Id 
    WHERE 
        Tonight.EventDate >= '30-May-2015' AND 
        Tonight.EventDate <= '31-Dec-2015' AND 
        Events.CanSellEntry <> 'no' AND 
        Events.EntryPrice > 0 AND 
        Tonight.CanSellEntry <> 'no' AND 
        Events.EventType = 'night'
) 
ORDER BY Events.EventName
```

Comment: Your data relationship is not clear but it seems to me that one event can have multiple instances on different tonights, which makes your query logic wrong. When you join the tonight table outside the sub query, you have no filter on date, which brings matched events from all nights. Try get rid of the sub query and join three tables directly.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Looking at this again this issue still exists when I join all tables together directly. It seems I can't filter down to only one row per event when there are multiple date rows for each event in the Tonight table